# Export to pdf | How to show option to open and save

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, export, export-to-pdf

I have this working code for exporting to pdf. When I export it , it asks me location to save file. Instead , I want to have option of OPEN or SAVE . Currently what I am doing is :

```
protected void btnPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView2.RenderControl(hw);
    GridView2.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
    GridView2.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
    GridView2.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
    GridView2.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
    GridView2.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file on the server

```
Response.TransmitFile(//FILE PATH);
```

If you don't

```
Response.BinaryWrite(//Pass Byte Array)
```